# Restoring Keyboard IRQ

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm very new to the Linux Kernel Module development and trying to write a simple kernel module which can later be extended as the keyboard driver.

I tried following two approaches:

1. Interrupt Based Approach

I started writing the code after following the guide given [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x1256.html). But the only problem is that the machine freezes when I run `rmmod` because it is not able to restore the IRQ to the original keyboard driver.

Is there any way to save the `device name` & `device id` of the original keyboard driver before requesting the IRQ in `init()` and then restore everything back to normal once the `exit()` i.e. `cleanup_module()` is fired?

```
void cleanup_module() {
    /* Something to restore everything back to normal */
    free_irq(1, NULL);
}
```

2. Polling Approach

In this approach, I am continuously polling for the Key Pressed & Released by using a `while` loop and then copying the input back to the user.

```
while(!(inb(0x64) & 0x1) || (input = inb(0x60)) & 0x80);
```

The problem I'm facing here is that it never comes out of the `while` loop. I'm assuming that is because the original keyboard driver serves the request.

Is there any way to get the request forwarded from the original keyboard driver?

I appreciate any help/pointers on this.

Thanks!

Comment: The final parameter of `free_irq` should not be `NULL`, must match the final parameter of `request_irq`, and must be unique for this IRQ number. The combination of the IRQ number and this final parameter value is what identifies the IRQ handler you are freeing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I do not see how this can work as long as the normal kernel keyboard driver is also controlling the keyboard, since both drivers will be attempting to control the device.  The kernel i8042 driver (I assume that is the relevant one for you) registers its interrupt as shared, and if your driver managed to register for the same interrupt then it will also have registered its handler as shared, so that both got notified on interrupts and would race to access the device.

If you registered a shared handler, this might also explain the crash when you unload it: unregistering a shared interrupt handler only works when the second parameter contains a valid dev_id; so unregistering would fail when called with NULL as you did, but the handler code would still be unloaded from memory.  This would leading to a crash on a future interrupt.

Regarding your polling approach, yes, since the normal driver is notified on interrupts it is rather likely to beat you to reading the keyboard.